# Wikidata: order by last updated item in specific date time range

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api

I noticed that when a query does not have an 'order by' statement at the end, the results are ordered in a last-updated-first manner.

```
SELECT ?subjectLabel ?subject WHERE {
  ?subject wdt:P31 wd:Q11424.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
} LIMIT 50
```

What if I wanted to control this and get all items that have been updated during the month of April 2021 only? I would like to limit the results in some way but I can't find the proper way of doing that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `SELECT ?subjectLabel ?subject ?date WHERE {
  ?subject wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 ;
           schema:dateModified ?date
  filter(year(?date) = 2021 && month(?date) = 4)
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
} LIMIT 50`

Comment: `SELECT ?subjectLabel ?subject ?date WHERE {
  ?subject wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .
     ?subject schema:dateModified ?date .
        hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe "true" .
  filter(?date >= "2021-04-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime && ?date <= "2021-04-31T23:59:59"^^xsd:dateTime)
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
} LIMIT 50`